# Use regex as a delimiter to break up undelimited text table

Tags: regex, excel, vba

Please let me start by saying I am not a programmer and this is my first stackoverflow question. So if I am not following typical etiquettes, I apologize in advance.

I am working on a VBA spreadsheet where I need to read a text file and import a data table similar to the one shown below. The table needs to be split into columns (18 columns in the table below) and stored into an array. I am using vba split function. However, my problem is that I could not find the regex that I can use as the delimiter for the split function.

**My Data Text Table**

```
 Layer   Depth     Unit    Damping    Shear      Max       Max      Shear       Depth      Max       G/Gmax        Damping       Motion         Depth     Input     Gmax         Average              CSR
                  Weight             Modulus    Strain    Stress   Wave Vel.   Max Acc     Acc       Curve          Curve         Type                     Vs                      PGA
          (m)    (kN/m^3)    (%)     (kN/m^2)    (%)     (kN/m^2)   (m/s)        (m)       (g)                                                  (m)       (m/s)   (kN/m^2)         (g)
  1       .749   18.8518         5  32682.88    .01486     4.856    130.3899         0    .35182  EPRI 0-20'    EPRI 0-20'       Outcrop         .749    149.99     43092         .34368             .223392
  2      2.749   14.9244       7.6  11773.69    .13396    15.771    87.95655     1.499    .34895  Peat          Peat             Within         2.749    111.98     19152       .3362193            .2185425
  3      5.749   16.4953      12.6  14589.03     .2003    29.225    93.13082     3.999      .309  Clay PI=20    Soil PI=15       Within         5.749    134.99   30643.2       .3095427            .2816547
  4      8.999   16.9666      12.5  21215.63    .19831    42.076    110.7365     7.499    .24429  Clay PI=20    Soil PI=15       Within         8.999    159.99  44336.88       .2829335              .30431
  5     11.499   18.5376      20.7   6717.56    .70629    47.431    59.61278    10.499    .20776  EPRI 21-50'   EPRI 21-50'      Within        11.499    164.99  51566.76       .2461606            .2820004
  6     13.499   16.9666      15.3  13023.36    .39452    51.386    86.76098    12.499    .23157  Clay PI=20    Soil PI=15       Within        13.499    149.99  38974.32       .2252097            .2667809
  7     16.999   19.0089       9.2  46419.66    .11855    55.032    154.7508    14.499    .23462  EPRI 51-120'  EPRI 51-120'     Within        16.999       220  93653.28       .1880533            .2302633
  8     21.999   19.0089      10.3  44873.13    .15853    71.136    152.1511    19.499    .21577  EPRI 51-120'  EPRI 51-120'     Within        21.999       230  102367.5       .1834982            .2296537
  9     26.999   19.0089      10.4  52672.79    .16092     84.76    164.8447    24.499    .21795  EPRI 51-120'  EPRI 51-120'     Within        26.999       250  120944.9       .1755987            .2227533
 10     32.249   19.0089       7.3  87558.16    .10769    94.289    212.5349    29.499    .20249  EPRI 121-250  EPRI 121-250     Within        32.249    279.99  151683.8       .1618781            .2073164
 11     38.999   19.0089       6.5  122831.4    .08732   107.252    251.7309    34.999    .20402  EPRI 121-250  EPRI 121-250     Within        38.999    319.98  198127.4       .1508976            .1948832
 12     46.998   19.0089         5  218390.3    .05743   125.428    335.6591    42.998     .1869  EPRI 121-250  EPRI 121-250     Within        46.998    399.99  309592.1       .1453711             .189016
 13     55.498   19.0089       4.5  287538.6    .04995   143.637      385.15    50.998    .17472  EPRI 121-250  EPRI 121-250     Within        55.498    450.01  391849.9         .14022            .1832357
 14       Base                                                                  59.998      .166                                 Within
 14    Outcrop                                                                  59.998    .23986                                 Outcrop
```

Comment: That looks like a fixed-width file so you might find it easier to use the Data >> From text option, choose the fixed-width setting and tweak the columns to match the data.  EDIT - on preview: what Nick said.  If you'd prefer to use VBA then you can read the file line by line and split each line according to the field boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the data you have is a fixed width. You can use a fixed width as part of the text import process. First, choose 'fixed width' rather than 'delimited'.

[image: First step of text import]

The second screen allows you to set the breakpoints for each column based on their widths.

[image: Select the column widths in data]

To do this in VBA, I would recommend looking at Chip Pearson's function at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ImportingFixedWidth.aspx

```
Function ImportFixedWidth(FileName As String, _
    StartCell As Range, _
    IgnoreBlankLines As Boolean, _
    SkipLinesBeginningWith As String, _
    ByVal FieldSpecs As String) As Long
```

You can set the width of each column in the `FieldSpecs` paramater

Comment: The process has to be completed using VBA since further analysis is completed using VBA codes and importing the tables and breaking it up manually would take a long time.

Comment: You can do a similar thing without regex in VBA since you know the field widths.

Comment: @alkustaban I have updated my answer to include another way in VBA.